# Smooth scroll not working on a tag inside p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, here is my snippet. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

```js
var OnePageNav = function() {
  $(".smoothscroll[href^='#'], #ftco-nav ul li a[href^='#'], .scroll-link li a[href^='#'], .scroll-button p a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hash = this.hash,
      navToggler = $('.navbar-toggler');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 700, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });


    if (navToggler.is(':visible')) {
      navToggler.click();
    }
  });
  $('body').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function() {
    console.log('nice');
  })
};
OnePageNav();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="700"><a href="#section-about" class="btn btn-outline-white px-4 py-3 scroll-button">About Us</a></p>

<section class="ftco-section" id="section-about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12  mb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
        <h1 class="ftco-heading heading-thin mb-5">Founded in 2014, Wholesale Xbox Live has been providing digital keys and game codes to over to over 50 countries worldwide at very competitive prices.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is `this.hash`? The  window has no `hash` property. Did you mean `location.hash`?

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm not sure as I pinched this bit of code from elsewhere. The other smooth scroll links work it's just this one that doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where did you get the code and what was the intent (and probably there are more code there) but there are some issues with your code:

1. `this.hash` is `undefined` which means `hash` will be undefined.
2. It doesn't matter because when you call to `e.preventDefault();` the `hash` will never changed.
3. The selector is not correct for the link you have in your example. Because the link has the class `scroll-button` but the selector contains `.scroll-button p a[href^='#']`. In your case it should be only `.scroll-button`.

So, to solve that issue, you can take the `hash` should be the `href` of the link. So, in your example, the link should lead to `#section-about` so you can grab the "hash" from the `href` attribute with `attr()` method.

```js
var OnePageNav = function() {
  $(".smoothscroll[href^='#'], #ftco-nav ul li a[href^='#'], .scroll-link li a[href^='#'], .scroll-button").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hash = $(this).attr('href'),
      navToggler = $('.navbar-toggler');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 700, function() {
      window.location.hash = '';
    });


    if (navToggler.is(':visible')) {
      navToggler.click();
    }
  });
  $('body').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function() {
    console.log('nice');
  })
};
OnePageNav();
```

```css
#section-about {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="700"><a href="#section-about" class="btn btn-outline-white px-4 py-3 scroll-button">About Us</a></p>

<section class="ftco-section" id="section-about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12  mb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
        <h1 class="ftco-heading heading-thin mb-5">Founded in 2014, Wholesale Xbox Live has been providing digital keys and game codes to over to over 50 countries worldwide at very competitive prices</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://output.jsbin.com/ceforal/7

**Notice** I removed the "easing" parameter because it doesn't including in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation!

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function (event) {

    var href = $(this.hash);

    if (href.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: href.offset().top - 85
        }, 750, function () {
            if (history.pushState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, '#' + href.attr('id'));
            } else {
                location.hash = href.attr('id');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.sec{
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head></head>

<body id="home">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav><a href="#section1">About Us</a></nav>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main>
        <h2 id="section1" class="sec">Founded in 2014, Wholesale Xbox Live has been providing digital keys and game codes to over to over 50 countries worldwide at very competitive prices</h2>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

See Example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4jk529v3/)